# ANT doesnt terminate openmp executable (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, ant, openmp, icc

When I'm starting an executable (OpenMP, C++, icc) in an ANT exec-task, the task does not terminate. After looking in the processes, I discovered that my process was died (defunct). The executable writes output and it seems quite properly. There is no problem without using OpenMP. There is also no problem when I start the executable without ANT. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. It seems that OpenMP gets a conflict with the C signal handler. If I turn off the C signal handler the execution of the the ANT exec-task terminates properly.